# Oracle/SQL - Using the rank function

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

What I'm trying to do is a list of persons from a table and in the event where a person exists more than once then return back their record that contains the highest ranked 'code'

Code ranking (high to low): T, E, F

So for the given dataset

```
Person  Code
----------------    
Tom     F
Paul    E
Mark    F
Paul    T
Mark    E
Chris   T
Chris   E
```

I would get the following back from my query

```
Person  Code
----------------
Tom     F
Paul    T
Mark    E
Chris   T
```

I'm assuming this is going to use the rank/analytic functions, but I'm just not familiar enough with them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest and most performant and Oracle specific solution:

```
SQL> create table mytable(person,code)
  2  as
  3  select 'Tom', 'F' from dual union all
  4  select 'Paul', 'E' from dual union all
  5  select 'Mark', 'F' from dual union all
  6  select 'Paul', 'T' from dual union all
  7  select 'Mark', 'E' from dual union all
  8  select 'Chris', 'T' from dual union all
  9  select 'Chris', 'E' from dual
 10  /

Table created.

SQL> select person
  2       , max(code) keep (dense_rank first order by decode(code,'T',1,'E',2,'F',3,4)) code
  3    from mytable
  4   group by person
  5  /

PERSO C
----- -
Chris T
Mark  E
Paul  T
Tom   F

4 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `RANK` function to rank the data

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with data as (
  2    select 'Tom' person, 'F' code from dual union all
  3    select 'Paul', 'E' from dual union all
  4    select 'Paul', 'T' from dual union all
  5    select 'Mark', 'F' from dual union all
  6    select 'Mark', 'E' from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9    from (select person,
 10                 code,
 11                 rank() over (partition by person
 12                                  order by (case when code='T' then 1
 13                                                 when code='E' then 2
 14                                                 when code='F' then 3
 15                                                 else null
 16                                             end)) rnk
 17*           from data)
SQL> /

PERS C        RNK
---- - ----------
Mark E          1
Mark F          2
Paul T          1
Paul E          2
Tom  F          1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Then, you just need to select the rows with a `RNK` of 1

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with data as (
  2    select 'Tom' person, 'F' code from dual union all
  3    select 'Paul', 'E' from dual union all
  4    select 'Paul', 'T' from dual union all
  5    select 'Mark', 'F' from dual union all
  6    select 'Mark', 'E' from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9    from (select person,
 10                 code,
 11                 rank() over (partition by person
 12                                  order by (case when code='T' then 1
 13                                                 when code='E' then 2
 14                                                 when code='F' then 3
 15                                                 else null
 16                                             end)) rnk
 17            from data)
 18*  where rnk = 1
SQL> /

PERS C        RNK
---- - ----------
Mark E          1
Paul T          1
Tom  F          1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Comment: Use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` if (person, code) can be duplicated, and you only want one (arbitrarily chosen) row returned. If (person, code) can be duplicated and you want a single row and you care which of the multiple rows, add additional criteria to the `order by`. You might want to think about storing the code to rank_value in a table and joining, instead of coding that into your stored procedure. There would be some cases where the benefits would out way the drawbacks of an additional table.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think RANK is what you need...

basically, your delete will look like this: (pseudo-query)

```
delete the rows from person
where that row is not in ( select the rows from person with the highest code )
```

**edit**:

this trick might help you too:

```
select person, code, decode( code, 'T', 1, 'E', 2, 'F', 3, 0 ) from mytable
```

Comment: Delete? I think he wants to query the max rank, not to delete data.

Comment: Correct I do not want to delete - just need to return a result for each person in the table. If a person is listed more than once than return the record with the highest 'code' ranking.  I can see how 'trim' could be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Hum... Alternative suggestion with standard SQL.
Have a `CODE_WEIGHT` table such as:

```
CODE WEIGHT
T    3    
E    2
F    1
```

Then group your query by Person (if this is the grouping criterion) and select the distinct code containing `max(weight)`.

I'll post the query in a couple of minutes.

**UPDATE**

Ok, sorry for the delay.

Here is a solution using the previous stated table and @Randy trick:

```
SELECT 
 pp.person, decode(max(c.weight), 3, 'T', 2, 'E', 1, 'F', '') code
FROM 
 person pp INNER JOIN code_weight c on (pp.code = c.code)
GROUP BY
 pp.person 
ORDER BY 
 person DESC;
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to dump Oracle proprietary function and get things done in pure SQL... Anyway, since you've asked for a Oracle solution, here it is.

**UPDATE 2**

And as promised, here's the best standard SQL version that I was able to come up with:

```
SELECT 
 p.person, c.code
FROM
(
 SELECT 
   pp.person, MAX(cc.weight) weight
 FROM 
  person pp INNER JOIN code_weight cc ON (pp.code = cc.code)
 GROUP BY
  pp.person 
) p INNER JOIN code_WEIGHT c ON (p.weight = c.weight)
ORDER BY
  p.person DESC;
```

Kinda ugly with the two joins... But it does the job without proprietary extensions. Any SQL guru knows how to optimize it?

Cheers,